# Step up DC/DC 5V -> 6V

Tags: power, voltage, dc-dc-converter

I have a circuit that runs 5V. I need to integrate a CO2 sensor that requires 6V. What would be the simplest, most cost effective way to do this? I need about 200ma for the sensor

Comment: Stock DC-DC boost regulator. 200mA wouldn't need very large discretes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*boardbite*'s TPS61040 is just one of many step-up converters which will do the job. But it costs 1.88 dollar in 1s at Digikey, while the cheapest I found is only 70 cent. That's the Semtech [SC4503](http://www.semtech.com/images/datasheet/sc4503.pdf).

[image]

This is the typical application schematic from the datasheet. Again, this will be similar for many other step-up switchers. The SC4503's reference voltage is typically 1.25 V, so for 6 V out you have to set R1 to 190 kΩ. At 12 V out and 200 mA the SC4503 will have a 90 % efficiency, for 6 V you can expect a slightly higher value. It can supply more than 1 A of output current, so you'll have lots of headroom. Comes in a SOT23-5 package, and the 1.3 MHz switching frequency means you only need a small inductor.

Comment: Nearly a third the cost, nice! May I ask which search/catalog you generally use for finding parts? Or is this Semtech part just from experience

Comment: For me always Digikey. I haven't purchased much from them (I use them for information!), but their on-line selection tools are excellent; I use them all the time. Direct links to manufacturer's site for datasheets on *all* parts as well. Just throw in the right parameters, and sort by price. IIRC I have used Semtech parts in the past, but the advantage of a site like Digikey ensures availability (they have 10 000 in stock), however exotic the brand may be.

Answer (score 2):

The **TPS61040** (from TI), among other adjustable-output step-up regulators, can accommodate 200 mA or more current draw at output voltage of 6V, from input voltage of 5V.

It is available in SOT23-5 package as well as 6-SON (similar to QFN), so you can start with a larger prototyping-friendly footprint, then move on to a smaller one for a final product.

Also, it's a fairly popular and inexpensive part, so you should have no trouble obtaining it. I think it costs a $1-2 in single-unit quantities.

I have used it before (for an LCD backlight application), and had good results with little layout effort (minimal number of peripheral parts, including a 10uH inductor).

Here is [its datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61040.pdf).

If you can't get that one, frankly there are dozens of options out there; just look under stepup/boost regulators in Digikey or Mouser. I just find that particular one to be convenient and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Check the acceptable voltage range for all your components. There's a good chance you can run both all of your logic AND the CO2 sensor at 5.5V, so you'd just need to adjust your primary supply.

Comment: If a logic IC's datasheet mentions 5.5 V as maximum for Recommended Operation Conditions, that's already 10 % margin included on a nominal 5.0 V. If you operate at 5.5 V and have a 10 % tolerance on that you may meet/exceed Absolute Maximum Ratings.

Comment: @stevenvh Sure, but plenty of 5V devices list 4.5-6V as the allowable range, and plenty of 6V devices allow 5-7.5V, so 5.5V makes everyone happy even with 10% tolerance.

Comment: In my experience that 6 V is often Absolute Maximum Ratings. Many users think that's maximum for normal operation, but it isn't. You should stay away from AMR.

Comment: also CO2 sensor requires 6v +/- .1v